# How to get this transition using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, transitions

I have bee experimenting with ffmpeg on video transitions , Now am stuck in this transition , I have no where to go ,

I have two videos like this,

[image]

at the end of first video i have to split the first video into two from center and reveal the second video like the following,

[image]
any help would be appreciated

Comment: ffmpeg is processing, not composition tool. But you can many tricks with it.

Comment: I think you'd need a [custom filter](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15962/video-transitions-and-filters-how-to-create-custom-ones?rq=1) to accomplish that. You might find [this](https://github.com/hudl/HudlFfmpeg/wiki/Creating-Custom-Filters) useful.

Answer (score 2):

Some variant of:

`ffmpeg -i FIRST -i SECOND -lavfi "blend=all_expr='if(lte((W/2-sqrt((X-W/2)*(X-W/2)))+N*SW,W/2),A,B)'" OUTPUT`

Comment: Amazing! It not as described author, but very impressive

Comment: Hey man, how to set custom time to complete this animation??? please inform me..., Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This needs a slightly elaborate filtergraph to do as described.

```
-filter_complex
    "[0]split[b1][b2];
     [b1]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[b1];
     [b2]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0[b2];
     [1][b1]overlay=x='0-(W/2)*(t-DUR0)/D':enable=gte(t,DUR0)[ob1];
     [ob1][b2]overlay=x='W/2+(W/2)*(t-DUR0)/D':enable=gte(t,DUR0)[fv]
    "
```

where `0` is video '1' and `1` is video '2'. `DUR0` should be replaced with duration of video '1' and `D` with duration of the effect.

---

A curtain effect, like what Paul described, can be done like this:

```
blend=all_expr='if(lte((W/2-abs(X-SW*W/2))/(SW*W/2),(T-S)/D),B,A)'
```

where `S` is start time in seconds. (You may want/need to adjust the timestamps of the top video 'A' beforehand using `setpts`) and `D` is duration of effect. These two variables should be replaced with the required numeral values.

I can't test either of these for a few days.